# ofstream will not write to a text file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am using Dev C++ to write to a text file using ofstream but it does not work, I have made a text file in dev c++and saved it and on another source file I wrote the following code:

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){

srand(time(0));
ofstream out(“hello.txt”);

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
          out << rand()%1000 << “ “;
out.close();


return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile this code I get an error and it highlights the following in red:

```
ofstream out(“hello.txt”);
```

It says hello undeclared.

The tutorials that I am following are from youtube and the programmer is using a Linux operating system, he is using g++, will the code still be the same on all operating systems? because I am using windows 7.

Comment: Change the quotes `“` to `"`. Voting to close as too localized.

Comment: Yeah I suppose it is actually

Comment: I was mentoring someone who was learning C++ through youtube tutorials. He had to break all sorts of bad habits. You must unlearn what you have learned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when I try to compile this code I get an error and it highlights the following in red:

Your quotes are "smart quotes". See how they're all bendy (`“”`), instead of straight (`""`)?

Use normal, straight quotation marks.

Do not program in Word. You may also have to change a Windows setting as I vaguely recall that some keyboard drivers have a smart quotes mode (which boggles the mind).

---

> The tutorials that I am following are from youtube and the programmer is using a Linux operating system, he is using g++, will the code still be the same on all operating systems? because I am using windows 7

For standard code like this yes, absolutely, by design.

When you start playing with OS-specific functionality (i.e. anything from POSIX or the Windows API) then it gets more complex, but you're not there yet.

And I can't recommend enough that you put down your "tutorials" and get [a *real C++ book*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

(It may even be that the smart quotes came from the tutorial website itself! If so, you should inform the author immediately.)

Comment: dev c++ isn't a good choice either :P

Comment: Thank you very much, I dont understand how it is possible for you to realise such a small thing so fast and from that, tell me it was done in word, amazing... I was following the tutorial away from home so I decided to use word to save my code into. @Paul, what is a better compiler?

Comment: @mamtarani: It's because I am a magical person.

Comment: @mamtarani: Dev-C++ is an IDE, not a compiler; the compiler you're using is MinGW GCC which is perfectly acceptable. However, Dev-C++ as an IDE hasn't been updated in some time so people like to get on your horse about it. _Code::Blocks_ is oft suggested as a substitute.

Comment: To keep things straight - there IS a currently developed branch of Dev-C++, containing G++ 4.7 and newer libraries. I *still* wouldn't recommend it, and just download Visual C++ Express Edition.

Comment: Switching compilers _as well_ seems a little extreme.